# c# jquery simple dialogbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am new to C# and JQuery. I try to add jquery to a C# WebForm project.
What I want to do is this:
Add a button to a webform.
If that button is clicked serverside then display a JQuery dialogbox

This is the code that I have - if I click the button nothing happens.
I wonder where the problem is....

.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="frmMain.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dialog_YES_NO_mit_JQuery.frmMain" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

  <title></title>

    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>        

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup(message) {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").html(message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });
    };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        Dialogbox using JQuery<br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDemo1" runat="server" OnClick="btnDemo1_Click" Text="Demo1" />
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.cs file  :

```
public partial class frmMain : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void btnDemo1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string message = "Message from server side";

            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript   (this.GetType(), "Popup",  "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);
              ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this link > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917243/recommendation-for-simple-jquery-dialog-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete example that works:

1. You need to add a reference to jQuery UI library after the reference to jQuery as this is where the dialog logic is defined
2. You need to add a reference to the jQuery UI CSS file to enable the modal popup styling.

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPopup(message) {
            $(function () {
                $("#dialog").html(message);

                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    modal: true
                });
            });
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Dialogbox using JQuery<br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDemo1" runat="server" OnClick="btnDemo1_Click" Text="Demo1" />
            <br />

            <div id="dialog"></div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**
[image: Modal popup working]

Answer (score 0):

here an example that works for me :

code behind :

```
    protected void ShowDialogClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ShowDialogJS();", true);
    }
```

aspx :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowDialogJS() {
        jQuery("#dialog").dialog();
    }
</script>


<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowDialog" Text="Show Dialog"
            OnClick="ShowDialogClick"></asp:Button>
```

EDIT : 
I have two js files for jQuery :

```
    <script src="ressources/jQuery/scripts/jquery-1.11.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ressources/jQuery/scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i re-edit my answer.. sorry, replace $("#dialog") with jQuery("#dialog")..
here an example without the call in code behind : http://jsfiddle.net/eKb8J/748/

Answer (score 0):

try this
aspx

`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

        Dialogbox using JQuery<br />

        <div id="dialog"></div>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDemo1" runat="server" OnClick="btnDemo1_Click" Text="Demo1" />
        <br />

    </div>
</form>
```

`

added
 `<div id="dialog"></div>`

i also added javascirpt files
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`